# tcblisting: two listings side by side

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

can anybody tell me, how to place two source doe listings side by side within a tcblisting?

Something like:

```
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,sidebyside, listing only,mathescape=true]
  Listing A some code

  \tcblower

  Listing B more code
  \end{tcolorbox}
```

But with real listings...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: BTW, run `texdoc tcolorbox`, see the page 59 of the `tcolorbox` manual (section 3.11 Side by Side).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use two source listings within a `tcblisting`, but you can put two listings side by side into a `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins,listings]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,sidebyside]
\begin{lstlisting}[style=tcblatex]
Listing A some code
\end{lstlisting}
\tcblower%-----------------------------------------
\begin{lstlisting}[style=tcblatex]
Listing B more code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]